# 2 accounts with same number

Tags: facebook-account

I created 2 accounts with the same phone number and deactivated one of them.
When I now go to make a post from pages other then Facebook it goes right to the account that is deactivated.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Since the account in question is just deactivated and not deleted all together, you can try the following:

- Reactivate the account.

  1. If it asks for a phone number, give a different one, reactivate, give just an email, delete the phone number and then delete the account altogether.
  2. If it doesn't, reactivate, delete the number giving just an email and then delete it altogether.